# returning Max value of select statement SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I pretty much forgot how to do this with SQL actually, the thing is I have an SQL select statement such as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) NAME FROM `SomeTable` WHERE `SomeID` = xxx GROUP BY `Field`
```

Which does return a table with one field and many records containing numbers. What I want is to get the a single value of the maximum number among those records.

Comment: If I search Google for your question title, the answer comes up first and second.  In other words, you didn't bother to research at all.

Comment: What about the [mysql MAX()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-max-function.htm) function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add LIMIT:

```
SELECT COUNT(`NAME`) AS `NUM` FROM `SomeTable` WHERE `SomeID` = xxx GROUP BY `Field` ORDER BY `NUM`  DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use descending ordering as well?

Comment: Isn't order by supposed to be specified before the grouping?

Answer (score 2):

it should help you. just use `MAX()` function

```
SELECT MAX(COUNT(*)) FROM `SomeTable` WHERE `SomeID` = xxx GROUP BY `Field`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select max(name) from
(
SELECT COUNT(*) NAME FROM `SomeTable` WHERE `SomeID` = xxx GROUP BY `Field`)a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) NAME 
FROM `SomeTable` 
WHERE `SomeID` = xxx 
GROUP BY `Field`
order by NAME desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want is to get the a single value of the maximum number among those
>   records.

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM SomeTable t1
(
     SELECT SomeID, Max(Field) MaxField
     FROM SomeTable
     GROUP BY SomeID
) t2 ON t1.SomeID = t2.SomeID AND t1.Field = t2.MaxField
WHERE t1.SomeID = xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a single result of the highest value against a filter, just use Max:

```
SELECT MAX(MyField) NAME 
FROM `SomeTable` 
WHERE `SomeID` = xxx;
```

Alternatively, if you want an aggregate grouped by another column, the syntax is like so:

```
SELECT Name, MAX(MyField) as MaxOfMyField -- Or COUNT(MyField) if you want the Count
FROM `SomeTable` 
WHERE `SomeID` = xxx 
GROUP By Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the MAX function is:

```
SELECT MAX(expression )
FROM tables
WHERE predicates;
```

Example

```
SELECT MAX(salary) as "Highest salary"
FROM employees;
```